# Flutter: go_router connect to flow_builder

Tags: flutter, dart

`go_router` can't use declarative flow of steps. Like steps of registration, where you can fill the form and call `goNext()`
But `flow_builder` can.
It allows you to have a list of steps, like: `[ Login(), Selfie(), EnterPhoneNumber(), CheckOTP(), Passport(), Finish() ].` And I can easily swap or remove them.
Is it possible to make them work together? Examples needed
Thanks in advance.